# Flutter Driver select date from date picker

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I would like to select a date through date picker as part of a flutter driver test. however, I can't seem to figure out exactly how I would do this?

I've tried using a `find.text`and`find.bySemanticsLabel`, and have tried but have had no luck thus far.

my code :

```
Future<void> executeStep() async {
  await FlutterDriverUtils.waitForFlutter(world.driver);
  NewOrderForm newOrderForm = NewOrderForm(world.driver);
  await newOrderForm.setFieldKontrak();
  //Open Date Picker
  await newOrderForm.setDateKontrak();
  //Select date 24
  await driver.waitFor(find.bySemanticsLabel('24'));
  await driver.tap(find.text('24'),timeout: Duration(seconds: 15));
  await driver.waitFor(find.text('OK'));
  await driver.tap(find.text('OK'));
  await newOrderForm.setProyekField();
```

}

Screen capture :

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran a sample test that selects a date from datepicker and it worked well. Below is what I did:

main.dart has a simple `RaisedButton` upon clicking on which `DatePicker` opens:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _showDatePicker();
          },
          child: Text('Click')
        )
      )
    );

void _showDatePicker() async {
    DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: new DateTime(2019),
        lastDate: new DateTime(2021)
    );
    if(picked != null) setState(() => _value = picked.toString());
  }
```

Below is the flutter driver test that first identifies the `RaisedButton` -> taps on it -> finds the date to be selected -> taps on it -> taps OK

```
test('datepicker test', () async {
        final dateButton = find.text('Click');
        await driver.waitFor(dateButton);
        await driver.tap(dateButton);
        await driver.tap(find.text('15'));
        await driver.tap(find.text('OK'));
        print('October 15 selected and tapped OK');
      });
```

Test result:

[image]

In the code you provided, you may try below snippet, ie, tap on `24` and directly tap on `OK` instead of telling driver to wait for `OK` button to find.

```
await driver.tap(find.text('24'));
  await driver.tap(find.text('OK'));
```

Hope this helps you to resolve the issue.

Comment: note that this does not work well with the Time picker. Tapping a text will result in another time being selected. Flutter needs to make integration testing more developer friendly when using those type of flutter widgets. It's a shame because 80% of testing is fast on flutter but the last 20% is really annoying to do.

Comment: Here I'm again, apparently. It also won't work with DateRangePicker as multiple days with the same text can be shown on the same page